# shortcut to toggle suspend autohotkeys?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

Sometimes when I am writing a script I don't want a particular script  - the one i'm writing - to be running.

I want to just write, then save it and refresh autohotkeys to get it running, then I see how it works it may not be how I want so want it to stop running the script.

I want to do this efficiently.

I see reload will unsuspend too.

So I want a shortcut to suspend

and a shortcut to reload.

And I want, for example, ctrl-r (Reload) to work even from a notepad window i'm typing in. Not just in the autohotkeys window.

Answer (score 0):

Will these help?

This will pause the script:

```
^p::Pause
```

This will reload:

```
^r::Reload
```